# c# md5 and php md5 not match

Tags: c#, php, md5

here is my c# compute signature code

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    string str;
    string syskey = "123456789";
    str = GenSignature(syskey,"foo","20170426001757");
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}

public static string GenSignature(string syskey,params string[] paramValues)
    {
        string source = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramValues[i]))
            {
                source += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) ? "" : "&") + paramValues[i];
            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        {
            return "";
        }

        source +=  "&" + syskey;
        // Debug.WriteLine(source);
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 m = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashData = m.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source));
            return BitConverter.ToString(hashData).Replace("-", "").ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

and the php get signature code is below:

```
function getSignature() {
    $syskey = "123456789";
    $sysCode =  "foo";
    $timeStamp = "20170426001757";
    $str = "&".$sysCode."&".$timeStamp."&".$syskey;
    return strtoupper(md5($str));
}
echo getSignature();
```

I do not know c# very well, but the result I get are totally different, Did any one know the two languages and tell me something, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PHP example you prepend every part with an ampersand (`&`), however in the C# version you prepend every part but the first:

```
source += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) ? "" : "&") + paramValues[i];
```

`string.IsNullOrEmpty(source)` will return `true` the first time since you initially set `source` to `""`, thus an ampersand won't get added in the very beginning of the string.

Change your code to this and it should work:

```
source += "&" + paramValues[i];
```

**Online test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KhoFtL**

Comment: OK,it works now, I have spend almost one day on it and think  little more complicated, really appreciate your help