# PHP MD5 output does not match C# MD5 output

Tags: c#, php, c#-4.0, hash, md5

in C# I'm trying to get a hashed md5 value of a password like so:

```
 string sb = textBox2.Text;
            byte[] asciiBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb);
            byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
            string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
 var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb);
            sb = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

in php I get that value by using md5 command,

```
echo md5("megusia94");
```

the input in both cases are the same,
yet the output in PHP is: d1e44ad921daadaf8defadcd21c8644a
while in C# the output is: bWVndXMpYTk0

What am I doing wrong? I've searched this forum and tried:
[MD5 hashing does not match in C# and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821677/md5-hashing-does-not-match-in-c-sharp-and-php)
[c# md5 and php md5 not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650593/c-sharp-md5-and-php-md5-not-match)

Comment: **You shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)**. Please use **PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)** (`password_hash()` and `password_verify()`) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). **It is not necessary** to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5821677/1415724

Comment: Fred, I tried the solution to that too...

Comment: the possible duplicate I posted above, is the very same used in the answer and from the accepted answer in the other question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing the same two things.
What you are comparing is the base64-representation of the ASCII-encoded input string with the actual MD5 hash (in HEX representation) from PHP.

Instead look at this:

```
byte[] asciiBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("megusia94");
byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
Console.WriteLine(hashedString);
```

It correctly produces the hash `d1e44ad921daadaf8defadcd21c8644a`, which is the same as the one you get from PHP.

Comment: Thank you this worked. I'm a bit rusty on my C# skills trying to refresh it. It was years since my last application written with this language.

Comment: @pokrak94 No problem. Please also note the advice from GrumpyCrouton and don't use this hashing scheme in any security related setting ;-) It's just so very flawed.

Comment: This is for a home application that I already have a php version of, now trying same in C#. Not gonna publish it or anything - just for the sake of practice. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

PHP md5:

- Returns the hash as a 32-character hexadecimal number.

Your C# code:

- Returns the hash with base64 encoding.